# json encode is not working with array of objects

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, encoding

I want to convert array of objects to json encoding, I make like this

```
$allVisits = $mapper->getAllVisits($year, $month);
echo json_encode($allVisits);
```

and here's is getAllVisists method

```
 function getAllVisits($year, $month) {
    $where = array(
        'year = ?' => $year,
        'month = ?' => $month
    );
     $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll( $where);
    $visitsEntries = array();
    foreach ($resultSet as $row) {

        $entry = new Visits_Model_Visit();
        $entry->setId($row->visit_id)
                ->setDay($row->day)
                ->setDate($row->date)
                ->setTarget($row->target)
                ->setStatus($row->visit_status)
                ->setTime($row->visit_time);

        $visitsEntries[] = $entry;
    }
    return $visitsEntries;
}
```

when I echo the size of $allVisits it return correct number of records, but in js the values are received empty like this [{},{},{},{}]

**Edit**

When I print_r($allVisists) brfore encoding it it returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Visits_Model_Visit Object
        (
            [day:private] => sunday
            [date:private] => 2012-03-06
            [target:private] => شسي
            [id:private] => 1
            [status:private] => 0
            [time:private] => 12:00:00
        )

    [1] => Visits_Model_Visit Object
        (
            [day:private] => sunday
            [date:private] => 2012-03-06
            [target:private] => clinnics
            [id:private] => 4
            [status:private] => 0
            [time:private] => 00:00:00
        )

    [2] => Visits_Model_Visit Object
        (
            [day:private] => Tuesday
            [date:private] => 2012-03-06
            [target:private] => clinnics
            [id:private] => 5
            [status:private] => 0
            [time:private] => 00:00:00
        )

    [3] => Visits_Model_Visit Object
        (
            [day:private] => Wednesday
            [date:private] => 2012-03-28
            [target:private] => ??????? ???????
            [id:private] => 7
            [status:private] => 0
            [time:private] => 12:00:00
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($allVisits)` before calling `json_encode`?

Comment: It print out the array properly

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) with objects that don't have any public members. `json_encode` only works on the members it can "see", that's why those are empty.

Since PHP 5.4 you can make use of the [`JsonSerializable` interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) to control which data will be offered for `json_encode`, e.g.:

```
class Visits_Model_Visit implements JsonSerializable {
    ...
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return (object) get_object_vars($this);
    }
    ...
}
```

If you are below 5.4 you can also implement that function w/o extending from the interface and then assigning the correct value manually:

```
$visitsEntries[] = $entry->jsonSerialize();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can implement JsonSerializable in earlier versions of PHP if you follow my approach below.

Answer (score 8):

As Ray says if your class properties are protected or private, these will not be jsoned.

Since PHP 5.4 instead of using the commented toJson method, you have the ability to specify which data will be serialized implementing the JsonSerializable interface, so json_encode knows how to work on this.

```
/* PHP >= 5.4 only */
class Visits_Model_Visit implements JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array(
             'day' => $this->day,
             'date' => $this->date,
             'target' => $this->target,
             'id' => $this->id,
             'status' => $this->status,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay for 5.4.  This will clean up a half dozen of my internal api's.  Fingers crossed the upgrade doesn't break my server.

Comment: @arraintxo my company is just now upgrading to php 5.3 :( I don't get the  JsonSerializable interface.

Comment: @Ray, my solution allows you to implement JsonSerialable in earlier versions of PHP.

Comment: Typo! ``implement`` vs. ``implements``

Answer (score 6):

By default, json_encode() only serializes public properties of an object.  Making all properties you want serialized public is *NOT* the solution!  PHP 5.4 and later has the JsonSerializable interface, but I propose a straightforward solution for earlier versions of PHP.

Since JsonSerializable is only part of PHP 5.4 and later, create it yourself.

```
if (!interface_exists('JsonSerializable')) {
   interface JsonSerializable {
      public function jsonSerialize();
   }
}
```

That wasn't so hard, was it?  Now we can implement JsonSerializable without worrying about what version of PHP we are using!

```
class Visits_Model_Visit implements JsonSerializable {
    ...
    // Only put properties here that you want serialized.
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return Array(
           'day'    => $this->day,
           'date'   => $this->date,
           'target' => $this->target,
           'id'     => $this->id,
           'status' => $this->status,
           'obj'    => $this->obj->jsonSerialize(), // example for other objects
           'time'   => $this->time
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you can just call jsonSerialize() to get an associative array that you can encode with `json_encode()`.

```
    ...
    $entry = new Visits_Model_Visit();
    $entry->setId($row->visit_id)
          ->setDay($row->day)
          ->setDate($row->date)
          ->setTarget($row->target)
          ->setStatus($row->visit_status)
          ->setTime($row->visit_time);

    $visitsEntries[] = $entry->jsonSerialize();
    ...
```

You may then call `json_encode($visitsEntries)` to get your desired result.

```
[
   {
      "day":"sunday",
      "date":"2012-03-06",
      "target":"\u0634\u0633\u064a",
      "id":1,
      "status":0,
      "time":"12:00:00"
   },
   {
      "day":"sunday",
      "date":"2012-03-06",
      "target":"clinnics",
      "id":4,
      "status":0,
      "time":"00:00:00"
   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: Why array? I want object - and question is "...array of OBJECTS"

Comment: An associative array because when you call json_encode() on it, it will convert to the proper JSON notation for an object.  The keys in the array will be the "object" property names, and the values will be, well, the values of those properties.  I will update my answer with the end result.

Comment: Update to my comment: json_encode() actually doesnt check if your passing in array or object so you have to explicitly cast it to whatever you need in output. So array is fine, its just PHP that I expected to be smarter then it actually is.

Answer (score 5):

Are the properties private or protected for the object?  If so, json encode can't see them inside the object.  I get around this by creating a 'toJson' method in my objects that I need to serialize into json. In this method, I walk the objects properties and manually construct a generic object, that I pass to json_encode.  Then I return the Json string from this method.

Do not just make all your object properties public!!!!

Comment: Agreed.  You would be mistaken to disagree with Ray's last bit of advice.

Answer (score -1):

For those who are looking for **simple answer**, unlike other complicated answers my is piece of art:

```
json_encode(array(
    Protocol::PARAM_CODE => Protocol::CODE_SUCCESS,
    Protocol::PARAM_USER => (object)$user->jsonSerialize()
));
```

Even when $user->jsonSerialize() outputs stdObject, json_encode is so dumb, it has no idea it is object so you have to state that **explicitly** with casting it to **(object)** - don't you love PHP for it's simplicity?

Comment: No. The Protocol:: class you are referencing

Comment: @user431806 Oh it is just class containing some constants for the client - server communication protocol. It is not important, important part is only that you have to explicitly cast the stdObject class to (object) because json_encode doesn't recognize it as object otherwise.