# Convert php array to a much much smaller json?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am receiving a PHP array from a webservice (soap xml).
From this array, I want to keep just a few tags and then convert it to json (see sample in the bottom).

See sample of the array I receive from webservice, below:

(*** marks the information I need in my final Json)

```
Array (
[0] => stdClass Object (
***[Id] => 445946
[SystemName] => 
[TrackingPixelUrl] => http://www.pix.se/picture.png
[UrlName] => Movie_Renoir_445946
***[Name] => Movie: Film
[ForeignProductId] =>
[PackageId] =>
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 12
[TemplateId] => 81
***[Image] => stdClass Object (
[MediaId] => 41315620
[MediaType] => Image
[Url] => http://images.pix.se
[Width] => 214
[Height] => 317
[ProducedBy] =>
[CopyrightBy] =>
[ImageType] => Image
)
[Status] => Active
[PublishedDate] => 2014-11-03T10:23:09.617
[RevisionDate] =>
[ExpirationDate] => 2014-11-14T00:00:00
[Relevance] => Regional
[ParentProductId] =>
[ProductType] => Product
[IsHighlight] =>
[Attributes] => stdClass Object (
[AttributeData] => Array (
[0] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 18895726
[AttributeId] => 125
[MetaType] => String
[Value] => stdClass Object (
***[Data] => http://www.Movie.se
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 1
[Language] => 1
)
[1] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 18895762
[AttributeId] => 102
[MetaType] => String
[Value] => stdClass Object (
***[Data] => Text text info tinfo text Long text
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 2
[Language] => 1
)
[2] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 20562011
[AttributeId] => 106
[MetaType] => String
[Value] => stdClass Object (
***[Data] => 70 SEK 
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 3
[Language] => 1
)
[3] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 27970127
[AttributeId] => 99
[MetaType] => String
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] => Movie: Film
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 11
[Language] => 1
)
[4] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 27970128
[AttributeId] => 101
[MetaType] => String
[Value] => stdClass Object (
***[Data] => Short info text text text
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 11
[Language] => 1
)
[5] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 18895724
[AttributeId] => 147
[MetaType] => String
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] => +46
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 2
[Language] => 0
)
[6] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 18895725
[AttributeId] => 145
[MetaType] => String
[Value] => stdClass Object (
***[Data] => (
0410-1111111
)
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 2
[Language] => 0
)
[7] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 18895728
[AttributeId] => 526
[MetaType] => Boolean
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] =>
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 1
[Language] => 0
)
[8] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 27970129
[AttributeId] => 115
[MetaType] => Media
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[MediaList] => stdClass Object (
[MediaObject] => stdClass Object (
[MediaId] => 41315620
[MediaType] => Image
[Url] => http://images.pix.se
[Width] => 214
[Height] => 317
[ProducedBy] =>
[CopyrightBy] =>
[ImageType] => Image
)
)
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 10
[Language] => 0
)
[9] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 27970130
[AttributeId] => 418
[MetaType] => MultiAttribute
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Values] => stdClass Object (
[MultiAttributeObject] => Array (
[0] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 0
[AttributeId] => 0
[ProductId] => 0
[OrganizationId] => 0
[MultiAttributeId] => 631
[MetaType] => Boolean
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] =>
)
[Language] => 0
)
[1] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 0
[AttributeId] => 0
[ProductId] => 0
[OrganizationId] => 0
[MultiAttributeId] => 36
[MetaType] => Boolean
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] =>
)
[Language] => 0
)
[2] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 0
[AttributeId] => 0
[ProductId] => 0
[OrganizationId] => 0
[MultiAttributeId] => 2030
[MetaType] => Boolean
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] =>
)
[Language] => 0
)
)
)
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 4
[Language] => 0
)
[10] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 27970131
[AttributeId] => 668
[MetaType] => MultiAttribute
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Values] => stdClass Object (
[MultiAttributeObject] => Array (
[0] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 0
[AttributeId] => 668
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[MultiAttributeId] => 2022
[MetaType] => Boolean
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] =>
)
[Language] => 0
)
[1] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 0
[AttributeId] => 668
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[MultiAttributeId] => 2023
[MetaType] => Boolean
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] =>
)
[Language] => 0
)
[2] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 0
[AttributeId] => 668
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[MultiAttributeId] => 2174
[MetaType] => Boolean
[Value] => stdClass Object (
[Data] =>
)
[Language] => 0
)
)
)
)
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Version] => 5
[Language] => 0
)
)
)
[Categories] => stdClass Object (
[Category] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 16015
[OrganizationId] => 1045
[Name] => Film
[DefaultTemplateId] => 81
[Status] => Active
[ParentCategoryId] => 3568
[DisplayOrder] => 99
[Icon] =>
)
)
[GeoNode] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 3558
[Name] => Staden med omnejd
[ParentId] => 66876
[OrgId] => 1045
[Type] => Undefined
[LeftValue] => 11
[RightValue] => 12
[CityCenterLatitude] =>
[CityCenterLongitude] =>
[CityCenterRadius] =>
)
[Occasions] => stdClass Object (
[OccasionObject] => stdClass Object (
[Id] => 19836976
[AttributeId] => 111
[ProductId] => 445946
[OrganizationId] => 1045
***[StartDate] => 2014-11-12T00:00:00
***[EndDate] => 2014-11-13T00:00:00
***[StartTime] => 0001-01-01T19:00:00
[EndTime] => 0001-01-01T19:00:00
***[ValidDays] => Wednesday Thursday
***[ArenaId] => 75316
***[ArenaName] => Moviegrafteatern Movie, Staden
[EntryTime] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
)
)
[SupplierId] =>
[Duration] =>
[ForeignProductIds] => stdClass Object (
)
[LanguageId] => 1
)
)
```

I would like the final, cropped, json to look like this:

```
  {  
      "Id":445946,
      "Name": "Movie: Film",
      "Image":{
         "Url":"http://images.pix.se",
         "Width":595,
         "Height":709
      },
      "MovieUrl": "http://www.Movie.se",
      "LongText": "Text text info tinfo text Long text",
      "Price": "70 SEK",
      "ShortText": "Short info text text text",
      "Phone": "0410-1111111",
      "StartDate": 2014-11-12T00:00:00,
      "EndDate": 2014-11-13T00:00:00,
      "StartTime": 0001-01-01T19:00:00,
      "ValidDays": "Wednesday Thursday",
      "ArenaId": 75316,
      "ArenaName": "Moviegrafteatern Movie, Staden"
      }
```

How can I convert this array to a much smaller JSON?

Comment: share the code you tried so far, what results you got... it's rare to find someone willing to code for you from scratch

Comment: Well, the bigger issue as I understand it is that you have too much information. Do you have any control over what gets returned in the original array?

Comment: I think you would be trying json_encode function on an array with object. that would be  wrong. If you r doing in such way so look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683687/json-encode-is-not-working-with-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to get this solved is an exakt mapping of your the items you need in a function an then loop through the different objects, because the structure you get with this lot of different objects is quite crappy.

```
function cleanUpResult(array)
{
    $r = array();
    foreach($item in $array){
     $result = array(); 

      $result["Id"] = $item["Id"];
      $result["Name"] = $item["Name"];
      $result["Image"] = array();
      $result["Image"]["Url"] =$item["Image"]->Url;
      $result["Image"]["Width"] =$item["Id"]->Width;
      $result["Image"]["Height"] =$item["Id"]->Height;
      $result["MovieUrl"] = $item["Attributes"]->AttributeData[0]->Value->Data;
      $result["LongText"] = $item["Attributes"]->AttributeData[1]->Value->Data;
      $result["Price"] = $item["Attributes"]->AttributeData[2]->Value->Data;;
      $result["ShortText"] = $item["Attributes"]->AttributeData[4]->Value->Data;
      $result["Phone"] = $item["Attributes"]->AttributeData[6]->Value->Data;
      $result["StartDate"] = $item["StartDate"];
      $result["EndDate"] = $item["EndDate"];
      $result["StartTime"] = $item["StartTime"];
      $result["ValidDays"] = $item["ValidDays"];
      $result["ArenaId"] = $item["ArenaId"];
      $result["ArenaName"] = $item["ArenaName"];
      $r[] = $result;
    }
    return json_encode($r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a list of the array keys you want to white list, then remove the rest.

Assume your object is $object

```
//this line must come before any output is made. (echo, print, etc.)
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//whitelist. the items you want to keep
$keep = array("id", "name", "image" ...);

foreach($object as $object) {

    foreach ($object as $key => $product) {

        if( !in_array($key, $keep) ) { //check if the current loop key is not in the whitelist
            unset($object[$key]);
        }

    }

}



//Then convert the array to JSon.

echo json_encode($object)
```

Then $object will hold only what was in the whitelist

Comment: OP has an array of **objects**, AFAIU. See `[0] => stdClass Object`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Updated for multi-dimension

Comment: `foreach ($object as $key => $product)` will fail because `$object` is not an array here. Take a look at the input data.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't complicated, but since you want various fields from within a nested array, the simplest approach is to just iterate over the array and grab the individual fields you want to encode. I'm not sure it'll be worth the time to construct a clever filter.

For example, let's say `$soapArray` contains the information you provided above:

```
$data = array();

// iterate over the full field list
foreach ($soapArray as $soapElement) {

    // construct a partial array containing the fields you want
    $data[] = array(
        'Id' => $soapElement['Id'],
        'Name' => $soapElement['Name'],
        'Image' => array(
            'Url' => $soapElement['Image']->Url,
            'Width' => $soapElement['Image']->Width,
            'Height' => $soapElement['Image']->Height,
        ),
        'MovieUrl' => $soapElement['Attributes']->AttributeData[0]->Value->Data,
        'LongText' => $soapElement['Attributes']->AttributeData[1]->Value->Data,
    );
}

// display the encoded array
echo json_encode($data);
```