# CodeIgniter - return paramater as row

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

This is my code as of now which returns Hassum Harrod profile as JSON which is perfect.  What I need to happen is for my parameter to be passed into the query string instead of having a name so that when the url is passed a name the query returns that person's profile from the DB.  When I change the name Hassum Harrod to the variable $name I get the following error:

Unknown column 'Hassum' in 'where clause'
SELECT name, short_name, reknown, bio FROM profile WHERE name = Hassum%20Harrod

This is my code as now:

**Controller**

```
public function getPerson($name) {
    // loads the DBModel.php                
    $this->load->model('DBModel');

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name, short_name, reknown, bio FROM profile WHERE name = 'Hassum Harrod'");

    $data['profile'] = $query->row();

    $this->load->view('profileView', $data);
```

}

**View**

```
echo json_encode($profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Read : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Try this way

**Add this method to your model it should be like this**

```
         // in your model
         public function getNames($name) {
            $data = array();
            $this->db->select(*);
            $this->db->like('name', $name);
            $query = $this->get('profile');
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                   $data[] = $row;
                }
            }

           return $data;
         }
```

**Your Controller should be like this**

```
  public function getPerson($name) {

      $this->load->model('DBModel');

      $data = $this->DBModel->getNames($name);

      // you can encode in json here
      $data['profile'] = json_encode($data);

      $this->load->view('profileView', $data);  
 }
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

**In view :**

```
       echo $profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `LIKE` keyword in your query so we could assume there would be more than one result in return from DB. In that case you would need `$query->result()` instead. Secondly, even if there is just one returned row, this code:

```
$data['profile'] = $query->row() > 0;// assigning variable to condition (TRUE|FALSE)
```

will return boolean value, but not result itself.

This is simplified code for that and you can check:

```
<?php

$a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var_dump($b = $a > 0);// TRUE
```

Feel free to start using basic examples from docs. It will help you maintaning code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$row = $query->row();

if (isset($row))
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

Again, if you expect only one possible row from DB, you can try with this code. But if you are not certain if there would be several possible rows, you have to use code for retreiving that:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

When you set this all working than you can work on converting object or array to JSON string.

It would follow syntax:

```
$json = json_encode($row);
```

If multiple rows is returned, it would be most easier to return result_array() or row_array() from DB since arrays are easily converted ti JSON, although there are [suitable solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683687/json-encode-is-not-working-with-array-of-objects).
After all, model that is loaded at the beginning of method is not used at all.

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html).

Comment: I have tried the doc example as shown above but then I get the error: Unknown column 'Barot' in 'where clause'

SELECT name, short_name, reknown, bio FROM profile WHERE name = Barot%20Bellingham

Comment: Seems you need `urldecode()` function first. Use it on `$name` variable before variable is passed to SQL syntax. Like: `$name = trim(urldecode($name))`. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php). Try to use propper code and coding standards. Use backticks over column and table names within SQL query.

Comment: Tpojka the snippet you gave me works perfectly thank you.  It was just what I needed.

Comment: If it was helpful, feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) (and vote up) the answer. #SOreadytohelp